# Implementing strategy when every strategy need different params

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have method that do 3 different thing based on user type, so i thought I can split it into strategies with factory that will return desired strategy based on user.type. So I will get:

```
strategy_interface.execute(product_id, user_id);
```

and then

```
strategy = strategy_factory.create(user.type);
strategy.execute(...);
```

but in reality method "execute" needs slighty different params for every user type:

```
if user.type is 1 then it needs only product_id
if user.type is 2 or 3 or 5 then it needs product_id and user_id
else it should only throw illegal_action_exception
```

I like my approach as it is easy to test. I have to check only instance type returned by factory but I have problem with that every returned strategy works differently. Maybe instead of universal factory I should do something like this:

```
if user.type is 1:
    strategy = new first_strategy();
    strategy.execute(...);
else if user.type is in(2, 3, 5):
    strategy = new second_strategy();
    strategy.execute(...);
throw new illegal_action_exception();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing your design to an if structure is a step back. I suggest you to adopt context object pattern into your design.
[image]

In my example, `StrategyContext` is a object that contains scoped data which is meaningful to your application. It encapsulates information you need for your different strategies. What it can holds depends on your application needs. I learn from your question that, for now there are `ProductId` and `UserId`.

`Strategy.execute()` could accept `StrategyContext`. In each implementation of `AlphaStrategy`, `BetaStrategy`, they can make use of the data inside `StrategyContext` and do their own business logic, without breaking the interface signature.

Of course, my answer is only a example. The data structure of `StrategyContext` does not have to be a map. And it does not have to be 'ContextScope' as the key. Sample code provided below.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// define the scope of context object for the application
enum ContextScope {
    ProductId, UserId

}

// StrategyContext store the data needed for Strategy
class StrategyContext {

    private Map<ContextScope, Object> context = new HashMap<ContextScope, Object>();

    public void set(ContextScope s, Object o) {
        this.context.put(s, o);
    }

    public Object get(ContextScope s) {
        return context.get(s);
    }
}

// Strategy interface
interface Strategy {
    public void execute(StrategyContext c);
}

// a mock Strategy which take only the product id
class AlphaStrategy implements Strategy {

    @Override
    public void execute(StrategyContext c) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Product Id:%s", c.get(ContextScope.ProductId)));
    }

}

// another mock Strategy which take both the product id and user id
class BetaStrategy implements Strategy {

    @Override
    public void execute(StrategyContext c) {
        System.out.println(
                String.format("Product Id:%s, User Id:%s", c.get(ContextScope.ProductId), c.get(ContextScope.UserId)));
    }

}

// The Factory to create different kinds of Strategy based on the user type. 
// The switch statement is not a good practice. But this is just a mock to make the demo runnable.  
class StrategyFactory {
    public Strategy create(int userType) {

        Strategy strategy = null;
        switch (userType) {
        case 1:
            strategy = new AlphaStrategy();
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 5:
            strategy = new BetaStrategy();
            break;
        }

        return strategy;

    }
}

public class StrategyPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StrategyFactory factory = new StrategyFactory();

        // AlphaStrategy
        System.out.println("AlphaStrategy - ");
        factory.create(1).execute(new StrategyContext() {
            {
                set(ContextScope.ProductId, 80);
            }
        });

        // BetaStrategy
        System.out.println("BetaStrategy - ");
        factory.create(5).execute(new StrategyContext() {
            {
                set(ContextScope.ProductId, 443);
                set(ContextScope.UserId, 200);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Output

```
AlphaStrategy - 
Product Id:80
BetaStrategy - 
Product Id:443, User Id:200
```